# SwiftUI - using variable count within ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a view created through a ForEach loop which needs to take a variable count within the ForEach itself i.e. I need the app to react to a dynamic count and change the UI accoridngly.

Here is the view I am trying to modify:

```
struct AnimatedTabSelector: View {
    let buttonDimensions: CGFloat
    @ObservedObject var tabBarViewModel: TabBarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).frame(height: 20)
                .background(Color.red)
            
            ForEach(1..<tabBarViewModel.activeFormIndex + 1) { _ in
                Spacer().frame(maxWidth: buttonDimensions).frame(height: 20)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).frame(height: 20)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            
            Circle().frame(
                width: buttonDimensions,
                height: buttonDimensions)
                .foregroundColor(
                    tabBarViewModel.activeForm.loginFormViewModel.colorScheme
                )
            
            ForEach(1..<tabBarViewModel.loginForms.count - tabBarViewModel.activeFormIndex) { _ in
                Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).frame(height: 20)
                    .background(Color.red)
                Spacer().frame(maxWidth: buttonDimensions).frame(height: 20)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            
            Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).frame(height: 20)
                .background(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

And the viewModel I am observing:

```
class TabBarViewModel: ObservableObject, TabBarCompatible {
    var loginForms: [LoginForm]
    @Published var activeForm: LoginForm
    @Published var activeFormIndex = 0
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(loginForms: [LoginForm]) {
        self.loginForms = loginForms
        self.activeForm = loginForms[0] /// First form is always active to begin
        setUpPublisher()
    }
    
    func setUpPublisher() {
        for i in 0..<loginForms.count {
            loginForms[i].loginFormViewModel.$isActive.sink { isActive in
                if isActive {
                    self.activeForm = self.loginForms[i]
                    self.activeFormIndex = i
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the loginFormViewModel:

```
class LoginFormViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive: Bool
    
    let name: String
    let icon: Image
    let colorScheme: Color
    
    init(isActive: Bool = false, name: String, icon: Image, colorScheme: Color) {
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.name = name
        self.icon = icon
        self.colorScheme = colorScheme
    }
}
```

Basically, a button on the login form itself sets its viewModel's isActive property to true. We listen for this in TabBarViewModel and set the activeFormIndex accordingly. This index is then used in the ForEach loop. Essentially, depending on the index selected, I need to generate more or less spacers in the AnimatedTabSelector view.

However, whilst the activeIndex variable is being correctly updated, the ForEach does not seem to react.

Update:

The AnimatedTabSelector is declared as part of this overall view:

```
struct TabIconsView: View {
    
    struct Constants {
        static let buttonDimensions: CGFloat = 50
        static let buttonIconSize: CGFloat = 25
        static let activeButtonColot = Color.white
        static let disabledButtonColor = Color.init(white: 0.8)
        
        struct Animation {
            static let stiffness: CGFloat = 330
            static let damping: CGFloat = 22
            static let velocity: CGFloat = 7
        }
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var tabBarViewModel: TabBarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AnimatedTabSelector(
                buttonDimensions: Constants.buttonDimensions,
                tabBarViewModel: tabBarViewModel)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                
                ForEach(tabBarViewModel.loginForms) { loginForm in
                    Button(action: {
                        loginForm.loginFormViewModel.isActive = true
                    }) {
                        loginForm.loginFormViewModel.icon
                            .font(.system(size: Constants.buttonIconSize))
                            .foregroundColor(
                                tabBarViewModel.activeForm.id == loginForm.id ? Constants.activeButtonColot : Constants.disabledButtonColor
                            )
                    }
                    .frame(width: Constants.buttonDimensions, height: Constants.buttonDimensions)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(
            stiffness: Constants.Animation.stiffness,
            damping: Constants.Animation.damping,
            initialVelocity: Constants.Animation.velocity)
        )
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I tried another way by adding another published to the AnimatedTabSelector itself to check that values are indeed being updated accordingly. So at the end of the HStack in this view I added:

```
.onAppear {
            tabBarViewModel.$activeFormIndex.sink { index in
                self.preCircleSpacers = index + 1
                self.postCircleSpacers = tabBarViewModel.loginForms.count - index
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        }
```

And of course I added the following variables to this view:

```
@State var preCircleSpacers = 1
@State var postCircleSpacers = 6
@State var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
```

Then in the ForEach loops I changed to:

```
ForEach(1..<preCircleSpacers)
```

and

```
ForEach(1..<postCircleSpacers)
```

respectively.

I added a break point in the new publisher declaration and it is indeed being updated with the expected figures. But the view is still failing to reflect the change in values

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your SwiftUI code to verify that `tabBarViewModel.loginForms.count` and `tabBarViewModel.activeFormIndex` are the value you think they are?

Comment: yes I have - they are definitely returning the expected values

Comment: So those values are correct, but the ForEach does not iterate the correct number of times related to those values, or the SwiftUI body doesn't get invoked again at all?  I'm not sure what you mean by "does not seem to react."

Comment: Sorry - yes so the SwiftUI body doesn't get invoked again. On first load all is fine, but when those values change, the view does not change i.e. the number of spacers does not change in accordance with the value changes

Comment: It looks like you're not missing any obvious annotations for SwiftUI.  Assuming you have verified the closure you pass to sink is being called as you expect, my guess would be you have more `TabBarViewModel` instances than you expect and one is being observed while another is being updated.

Comment: How are you using `AnimatedTabSelector`? That seems like the sort of view that you would call from a parent view to essentially decorate your view. If so, you can always define the values you are trying to change the view on as let constants, and let the changing `StateObject/ObservedObject` in the parent create the refresh.

Comment: So you mean have the constants in AnimatedTabSelector and pass these through in the parent view? But I still have the same problem - the ForEach is just not getting updated with the new values...

Answer (score 0):

OK so I seem to have found a solution - what I am presuming is that ForEach containing a range does not update dynamically in the same way that ForEach containing an array of objects does.

So rather than:

```
ForEach(0..<tabBarViewModel.loginForms.count)
```

etc.

I changed it to:

```
ForEach(tabBarViewModel.loginForms.prefix(tabBarViewModel.activeFormIndex))
```

This way I still iterate the required number of times but the ForEach updates dynamically with the correct number of items in the array

Comment: Looks like [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u) does say as much: "The instance only reads the initial value of the provided data and doesn’t need to identify views across updates. To compute views on demand over a dynamic range, use ForEach/init(_:id:content:)."